# Turning a PDE $f_t(t,x)+f_x(t,x)b(t,x)+\frac{1}{2}f_{xx}(t,x)\sigma^2(t,x)$ into a ODE given that $b$ and $\sigma$ are independent of $t$.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Assume that $f:[0,\infty) \times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb R$ is a function such that
$x \mapsto f(t,x)$ is monotone; the derivatives $f_t, f_x, f_{xx}$ exist and are continuous; $g(t,\cdot):=f^{-1}(t,\cdot)$ exists for each $t$, i.e. $f(t,g(t,x))=g(t,f(t,x))=x.$

Now set $z=f(t,x)$ and define $$\bar{b}(t,z)=f_t(t,x)+f_x(t,x)b(t,x)+\frac{1}{2}f_{xx}(t,x)\sigma^2(t,x).$$

In the below writing, given that $\bar{b}\equiv0$ and $b$, $\sigma$ are independent of $t$, why do we get $f_t$=0 as well?

Also, why do we get the PDE to be independent of $t$ altogether, i.e. $f_x$ and $f_{xx}$ are also independent of $t$?

[image]

Comment: Is it really $z=f(t,x)$? Not $z=g(t,x)$?

Comment: @MikaelHelin Yes we set $z=f(t,x)$ and $ x= g(t,z)$.

Comment: This appears to be wrong, nothing there forces the time independence of $f$. What you can say is that if $b,σ$ are time independent, then it is possible to ask for time independent solutions $f$. But these stationary solutions are a special solution class among the more general solutions.

Comment: Differentiate $f(t,g(t,x))=x$ with respect to $t$ to obtain
$$
f_t(t,x)+f_x(t,x)g_t(t,x)=0.
$$
Differentiate $x=g(t,x)$ with respect to $t$ to obtain $g_t=0$ then $f_t(t,x)=0$??

Comment: @MikaelHelin I don't think this is correct as you don't use $b$ or $\sigma$. And we should have $f_t(t,g(t,x))) + f_x(t,g(t,x))g_t(t,x)) = 0$.

Comment: The diffusion $\sigma$ does does not appear from nowhere. Take for example the heat eqaution $u_t-u_{xx}=0$ and there $u(t)$ is not zero.

Comment: @MikaelHelin I mean your argument doesn't use the assumptions that $b_t = \sigma_t = 0$.

Comment: I am looking here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula
Is there any help for you?

Comment: @MikaelHelin No I am not finding this very useful.